# How to calculate the difference of two numbers in c++?

Tags: c++

If I enable double and integer only, then it is 4 functions. But I want to enable all data types (int long float double unsigned numbers etc.) How is it possible?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

double diff(int num1, int num2) {
    return double(num1-num2);
}

double diff(int num1, double num2) {
    return double(num1)-num2;
}

double diff(double num1, int num2) {
    return num1-double(num2);
}

double diff(double num1, double num2) {
    return num1-num2;
}

int main() {
    int a = 10;
    double b = 4.4;
    cout << diff(a, b) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Just say `a - b`, forget about this `diff`. C++ compiler will select best method to make this calculation.

Comment: Thanks for the -1. I don't want to use the diff function. I just wanted to understand how it works...

Comment: This is a poor example of your problem (which may not even exist). There are standard arithmetic conversions which happen automatically, so you only need the `double(double, double)` version.

Comment: I do not understand why this question should be down-voted. While it does come from a newbie, and in this particular case you could just use a - b, it is an interesting way to show how and why to use templates. It might also come handy should you use objects rather than simple data types, e.g. matrixes or functions.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
template <typename T, typename U>
double diff(T a, U b) {
    return a - b;
}
```

You don't need the cast to `double` -- this is done for you if either argument is a `double`, and during `return` when both are integers. However,

```
double diff(double a, double b);
```

can be called with `int` arguments as well.

Comment: That's not much better of what he has already, unless you make the return type generic as well?

Comment: @thedayofcondor: I don't understand your comment. It solves the problem using a single function instead of four or more.

Comment: What I mean is double diff(double,double) would solve his problem as well... should diff(int,int) return a double or an int?

Comment: @larsmans I believe thedayofcondor means the template would make a bit more sense if it's signature was `template<typename T, typename U> auto diff(T a, U b) -> decltype(a-b);`. Which is a valid concern, although it doesn't really have to do all that much to do with the problem the author is trying to solve.

Answer (score 8):

Use a template function:

```
template <typename T1, typename T2>
double diff(const T1& lhs, const T2& rhs)
{
  return lhs - rhs;
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't like it if my difference of `int`s returned a `double`. Or the difference of `complex<double>`s, for that matter. Deduce the return type from the parameters and we have a deal.

Comment: @DanielFischer: a `double` return type matches the OP's spec.

Comment: @larsmans Just saw that, to my dismay. So up goes the vote for this solution.

Answer (score 4):

You don't have to "enable" operations, just write:

```
cout << (a - b) << endl;
```

Comment: I guess the difference is just an example... he wants to know about templates

Comment: The question states "How to calculate the difference of two numbers in c++?"

Answer (score 3):

Unlike all of previous answers I would add about C++11. In C++11 you can use `decltype`.

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T1, typename T2>
auto diff(T1 a, T2 b) -> decltype(a)
{
   return (a - b);
}

int main() {
   std::cout << diff(3.5, 1) << std::endl;
   std::cout << diff(3, 1.5) << std::endl;
}
```

`diff` function will always return value of type like first argument. Note in first case it is float number, but in second it is integer.

Comment: you could use `decltype(a - b)`

Answer (score 1):

You could define a template for the same

```
template <typename T, typename U>
T diff(const T& a, const U& b) {
    return a - b;
}
```

This code makes a lot of assumptions, like operator - is defined for T, and return type will be always of type T and so on...

Answer (score 1):

You could always calculate the difference using absolute values, for instance

```
cout << abs(a - b) << endl;
```

you might want to use templates like previous answers said though.